# Problem with membership on behalf of orgnization

Tags: wordpress, civimember

We accept registrations on behalf of organizations.  We have been requiring users to provide organization level data when purchasing a membership.  However, after filling out the membership contribution page and clicking Next to confirm the data, the organization level data does not show on the confirmation screen.  Additionally, after clicking the button to finalize the payment, we receive error messages that all organization level data is missing and must be provided even though we have filled in the data.  We have noticed that if we make the organization level information optional, rather than required, and the user chooses to register on behalf of an organization, the process works fine.

We are running 4.7.3 with WordPress 4.4.2.

Error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: So you added more fields to the Profile used for Organisation? I recall some issue recently regarding required/optional - ah found it - in case it has any relation to this issue https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-9067

Comment: We are experience same issue on a WP 4.4.2 and CiviCRM 4.6.14. The organizational membership profile is required and all fields in it are required. All fields are filled out and on the final page after confirmation to pay it appears as if all fields are empty and need to be filed out.

Answer (score 2):

4.7.6 seems to have resolved this issue