# CiviCRM issue when subscribing on behalf of an organisation with 4.7.3 and 4.7.4 releases

Tags: civimember, forms

A few weeks ago, my team started using CiviCRM (4.7.1) with Drupal (7.42). We created different Web pages to test different membership types (individual and on behalf of organization). Everything seemed to be good back then. When someone subscribed on behalf of an organization, both types of contacts were created and a relationship (Employer/Employee) was set. We upgraded to CiviCRM  4.7.3 and now when someone subscribes on behalf of an organization, only the contact is created, not the organization anymore. Same issue with the 4.7.4 release.

Once the membership is submitted:

with 4.7.1:

```
Notice : Array to string conversion dans   CRM_Contribute_Form_ContributionBase->buildCustom() (ligne 650 dans ******/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/ContributionBase.php).
Notice : Array to string conversion dans    CRM_Contribute_Form_ContributionBase->buildCustom() (ligne 650 dans ******/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/ContributionBase.php).
Notice : Undefined index: html_type dans CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->buildQuickForm() (ligne 520 dans ******/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php).
Notice : Array to string conversion dans CRM_Contribute_Form_ContributionBase->buildCustom() (ligne 650 dans ******/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/ContributionBase.php).
Notice : Array to string conversion dans CRM_Contribute_Form_ContributionBase->buildCustom() (ligne 650 dans ******/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/ContributionBase.php).
```

with 4.7.3 or 4.7.4:

```
Notice : Array to string conversion dans CRM_Contribute_Form_ContributionBase->buildCustom() (ligne 650 dans ******/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/ContributionBase.php).
Notice : Array to string conversion dans CRM_Contribute_Form_ContributionBase->buildCustom() (ligne 650 dans ******/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/ContributionBase.php).
Notice : Undefined index: html_type dans CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->buildQuickForm() (ligne 521 dans ******/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php).
Notice : Undefined offset: 0 dans CRM_Financial_BAO_FinancialAccount::getFinancialAccountForFinancialTypeByRelationship() (ligne 235 dans ******/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/FinancialAccount.php).
Notice : Array to string conversion dans CRM_Contribute_Form_ContributionBase->buildCustom() (ligne 650 dans ******/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/ContributionBase.php).
Notice : Array to string conversion dans CRM_Contribute_Form_ContributionBase->buildCustom() (ligne 650 dans ******/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/ContributionBase.php).
```

The only difference is a new bug from 4.7.3:

```
Notice : Undefined offset: 0 dans CRM_Financial_BAO_FinancialAccount::getFinancialAccountForFinancialTypeByRelationship() (ligne 235 dans ******/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/FinancialAccount.php).
```

We tried this on the demo site and we have the same behavior. See http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=4

Any hint would be welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it to be 'optional' and it worked for me. http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=225

Can you confirm this is the issue?

I  feel like this has come up recently but don't have time to search SE or JIRA - can you try and track down if an issue exists, or if one has been 'fixed' recently, then reopen it?

Comment: It does work when we make it optional, but our requirements are to make it required. Our point is that it worked fine in 4.7.1 and now it doesn't anymore. There is a related post http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10211/problem-with-membership-on-behalf-of-orgnization where you pointed to https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-9067. I don't seem to be able to reopen the bug but I added a comment.

Comment: Possibly related: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17878 and https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18219 ?

Comment: I re-opened : https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17878