# Honoree not created

Tags: honoree

I am testing a contribution form using the honoree profile and the contact added is not being saved or created. I am using CiviCRM 4.6.14 and WordPress 4.4.2.

There are not errors through the process and the donation is recorded, but not honoree details are. They appear blank on the confirmation page too.

Thoughts on why this might be happening?

Comment: Note: Wonder if this issue could be related: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10211/problem-with-membership-on-behalf-of-orgnization it's same instance of Civi and both profile are on the first tab of contribution page settings.